# pass EditText to a string

Tags: android-edittext

```
         EditText hi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         String hi2 = hi.toString();

         editor.putString("user_email", hi2);   
     editor.commit();
```

The code above in my on click works and compiles fine but the value i get when i go into my settings is

```
androd.widget.EditText@414e4e70
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax for me to pass a value from a user input box into a my pref.

if i use

```
editor.putString("user_email","helloworld@google.com");
```

then it works because its a full string.

Answer (score 0):

```
         EditText hi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         String hi2 = hi.getEditableText().toString();

         editor.putString("user_email", hi2);   //put into the email settings the value from the user input
         editor.commit();
```

I missed the getEditableText()
Late night coding :(